# My home is the air, the earth, and the sea

Tags: riddle

My home is the air, the earth, and the sea,
Between highs and lows you are sure to find me.
I am boisterous and loud, as bright as the sun,
But those who can see me or hear me are none.
I am born with a goal, I live in a shell,
I accompany those who greet and farewell.
I have numerous forms, interactions that last,
Like the tooth of a saw or the shock of a blast.
As fast as the wind, I fly through the dark,
None can outrun me, not falcon nor shark.
My essence is motion, my voice is a trill.
Occasionally I will attempt to stand still.
I live everywhere, both far and near,
But when you try to find me, I disappear.

This riddle is from SBHacks 2021!

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> WAVE?

*My home is the air, the earth, and the sea,*

> Waves can travel through the air, the earth, or of course the sea.

*Between highs and lows you are sure to find me.*

> Waves are made up of highs and lows.

*I am boisterous and loud, as bright as the sun,*

> Sound waves are loud, light waves are bright.

*But those who can see me or hear me are none.*

> You can't see the wave shape in light or hear it in sound.

*I am born with a goal, I live in a shell,*

> No idea about the shell.

*I accompany those who greet and farewell.*

> Waving hello or goodbye.

*I have numerous forms, interactions that last,*

> Many types of waves ...

*Like the tooth of a saw or the shock of a blast.*

> Such as the zigzag shape of a saw blade, or shock waves.

*As fast as the wind, I fly through the dark,*

> Sound waves?

*None can outrun me, not falcon nor shark.*

> Light waves are the fastest thing in the universe.

*My essence is motion, my voice is a trill.*

> Waves are always moving.

*Occasionally I will attempt to stand still.*

> Not sure about this or the "trill" from the last line.

*I live everywhere, both far and near,*

> Waves are everywhere.

*But when you try to find me, I disappear.*

> If you try to pin down a wave, it stops moving and it's not a wave any more?

Comment: I like this answer.  Some further justification?  rot13(Lbh pna yvfgra gb "gur fbhaq bs gur jnirf" va n furyy... gubhtu gung vfa'g jung lbh npghnyyl urne. "Gevyy" va gur frafr bs zhfvp vf bfpvyyngvat orgjrra gjb abgrf va n xvaq bs jnir.  "Fgnaqvat Jnirf" ner n guvat jurer gur nzcyvghqr vf punatvat ohg gur mrebf ner abg zbivat va gur fcngvny qvzrafvba.  Naq V thrff gur ynfg yvar vf n dhnaghz culfvpf ersrerapr?)